# Algorithm for finding cut vertex and bridge in directed graph

Tags: graphs, minimum-cuts

In un-directed graph it is easy to find cut vertex and bridge but in directed graph removing cut vertex/bridge must increase number of strongly connected componenets.

Comment: What is your question?  I don't see a question here.  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific, answerable technical question.  Also, it's helpful to tell us what research you've done, what approaches you've considered, and why you've rejected them.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on asking.  Can I invite you to edit your post to clarify your question?